# App invite does not show appInvitePreviewImageURL image (iOS , Android)

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-invite-friends

Initially my app does not included appInvitePreviewImageURL, so invite dialog was showing blank image. Now i have added appInvitePreviewImageURL with a valid url, i can open image in browser. Still i can't see the image App invite dialog.

**i'm using this code in iOS**

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
    content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:APP_URL_LINK];
    //optionally set previewImageURL
    content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:INVITE_IMAGE_URL];

    // Present the dialog. Assumes self is a view controller
    // which implements the protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`.
    [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:self
                                     withContent:content
                                        delegate:self];
```

**and using this code in android**

```
if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
   AppInviteContent content1 = new AppInviteContent.Builder().setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
     .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl).build();
   AppInviteDialog.show(activity, content1);
  }
```

Both platform facing same issue. Is it some cache issue?

[image]

Comment: I am facing same issue with Facebook App-invite. Still finding the solution.
I have reported this issue on facebook supports as well but bug not fixed.

Comment: Have you printed the value of `[NSURL URLWithString:INVITE_IMAGE_URL];`. I suspect it may be `nil`. If not then you should raise a bug in FB.

Comment: Just to help things along, I got the same url working on android. It was http not http, and showed a PNG not JPEG. So I'm thinking it's either iOS specific or something is being cached.

Comment: any luck with this? the FB documentation says if a previewImageURL is not set the invite will use Promotional Images from the App Details section in apps settings. however, there seems to be no such section. Typical example of documentation not reflecting current product.